# Product Quantity will decrease When Order is Placed in ASP.net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sql-server

I have One **product table** with a column **quantity** and a **cart table** with **productId** and **PurchaseQuantity** column.
what is the code for selecting all the productId and PurchaseQuantity from cart table(it can be more than one) according to the clientId. After that, the particular product quantity decreases according to the purchasedQuantity.
eg:

```
product table
productid      Quantity
  1                  10
  2                  20

cart table
productId     purchasedQuantity
   1                  5
   2                  3


 now product table will be
 productid      Quantity
   1                  5
   2                  17
```

what will be the SQL query for this?? any solution??

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.productid, p.Quantity-ct.purchasedQuantity
from product p
left join carttable ct 
on p.productid=ct.productid
```